# Failed to load resource: server responded with status of 404. Cannot load js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jqxgrid

I am trying to use jqxGrid.  I am trying to link to the js files.  Here is the structure of the project

Main Project

src
(below within src folder)

index.html

jqwidgets folder

Within the index.html I have links to the js as such

```
<script src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="jqwidgets/jqxdraw.js"></script>
<script src="jqwidgets/jqxbargauge.js"></script>
```

Here is some documentation
[Angular components doc](http://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/)

Also a demo of what I want to achieve
[demo](http://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-grid/index.htm#http://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-grid/angular-grid-defaultfunctionality.htm)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: some information you could edit into the question : what server are you using to host? how is it configured? do you get the 404 for all three scripts, or just a particular one?

Comment: I am using a localhost, Main Project folder > src > index.html and jdwidgets folder, and I get the 404 for all three scripts

Comment: Did that answer your questions?

Comment: Not really('localhost' is not a server software, do you mean you are just opening the `index.html` with your browser?) , but it's not important. If the project is set up the way you say it should work, so there's not enough information being given for us to say what the problem is.

Comment: To clarify, I replicated your project setup and opened `index.html` and got no 404s, the js files are loaded : http://i.imgur.com/HNaBliu.png . So I can't say why it doesn't work for you.